# Events don't work until video has buffered

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, vimeo-api

I am using the javascript api with vimeo, and I find that if I seek to a particular position in the video and then call 'play' that the video plays, but an event that I bound to 'play' does not fire.  If the video plays to the end (or near the end) so that the entire video has cached on my PC, at that point everything starts working.  For unknown reasons, vimeo has not replied on this question.  So I'm asking a more general question - for any videos - youtube, vimeo, videotag etc, have other programmers run into this issue?  (code is below, note that to seek you need to click on the 'next' button)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href='/Styles/common.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var globalcount = 0;
        var windowwidth = 0;

        var initialseek = true;
        var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        var timeoutID;
        var stoparray = new Array("48", "103.979", "346.513", "407.459");
        var quiz = false;

        var startPosition = 0;
        var stoplength = stoparray.length;
        var stopindex = -1;
        var timeinterval = 10;
        var defaultwidth = 3;
        var gDuration;
        var gPlayer;
        var gvideowidth;
        var gvideoheight;
        var hiderank;
        var gPlayer;
        var vimeoPlayers;

    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <center>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:33%;text-align:right;padding-right:14px"></td>
                <td style="width:33%">
                    <div id="HoldPlayer" style="position:relative">
                        <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/152639172?autoplay=0&api=1&player_id=player1'
                                id='player1'
                                width='640' height='360'
                                frameborder='0'></iframe>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width:33%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    Window (total time in seconds): <input type="text" id="windowwidth" maxlength="3" style="width: 30px;" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="chkplayvid" />Play</label>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </center>


    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="button" id="nextbutton" onclick="nextPlayer(); return (false);" value="Next" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </center>

    <div id="oPara"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        // +++++++++++++
        function ready2() {

            setupEventListeners();
            gPlayer.api('getDuration', function (value, player_id) {
                gDuration = value; // this will be set whenever callback fires
                playVideo();
            });

        }
        // +++++++++++++
        function setupEventListeners() {
            gPlayer.addEvent('pause', pauseEvent);
            gPlayer.addEvent('finish', endEvent);
            gPlayer.addEvent('play', playEvent);
        }


        function endEvent() {
            alert("end event!!!");
            gidClearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }
        function pauseEvent() {
            alert("pauseEvent!!!");
            return;
        }
        function playEvent() {
            alert("playEvent!!!");
            globalcount = globalcount + 1;

            if (initialseek) {
                timeoutID = setTimeout(pausePlayer, 60);
                initialseek = false;
            }
            else {
                timeoutID = setTimeout(pausePlayer, windowwidth);
            }
            return;
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#windowwidth").val(defaultwidth);
            setTimeout(addReadyEvent, 60);
        });
        // +++++++++++++
        function addReadyEvent() {

            var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
            gPlayer = $f(iframe);
            gPlayer.addEvent('ready', ready2);
        }

        // +++++++++++++
        function showNextButton() {
            $("#nextbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        // +++++++++++++
        function playVideo() {

            gPlayer.api('play');
            return;
        }
        // +++++++++++++
        function pausePlayer() {

            gPlayer.api('pause');
            $("#nextbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
            return true;
        }

        // +++++++++++++
        function nextPlayer() {
            var startPosition = 0;
            var str = "";
            var prevpos = -5;
            var stopPosition = 0;

            var dur = gDuration;
            windowwidth = 3;
            windowwidth = parseFloat(windowwidth);
            if (isNaN(windowwidth)) {
                windowwidth = defaultwidth;
            }
            if (windowwidth < 1) {
                windowwidth = 1;
            }
            if (windowwidth > 3600) {
                windowwidth = 3600;
            }
            windowwidth = Math.round(windowwidth);
            stopindex = stopindex + 1;


            stopPosition = parseFloat(stoparray[stopindex]);

            if (stopPosition > dur) {
                stopPosition = dur;
            }
            /* was here */

            startPosition = parseInt(stopPosition - windowwidth, 10);


            gPlayer.api('seekTo', startPosition);
            gPlayer.api('pause');
            setTimeout(playVideo, 60);

            return false;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo responded: a workaround is to play the video first, do the seek right after, and the playEvent will fire.  Actually to me, it seems that the call to seek has to be the end of any sequence of calls.